# Getting following error while creating a user in WSO2 IS 5.9.0 using scim API?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

My username is mapped to email while creating a user with payload

```
{
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User"
    ],
    "name": {
        "formatted": "Careerex Admin"
    },
    "userName": "careerex.admin@in.aanasonic.com",
    "password": "abc!12345",
    "profileUrl": "www.gmail.com",

    "phoneNumbers": [
        {
            "type": "mobile",
            "value": "9876543210"
        }
    ],
    "locale": "Delhi"
}
```

I am getting following error regarding restrictions of username-

```
{
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:Error"
    ],
    "scimType": "invalidValue",
    "detail": "31301 - Username careerex.admin@in.aanasonic.com is not valid. User name must be a non null string with following format, ^[\\S]{3,30}$",
    "status": "400"
}
```

Please help how to fix this and create user with same email???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default configuration available in WSO2 Identity Server enforces the username to be a string with a length of 3 to 30 non-empty characters. Your usecase requires the username length to be more than the default range provided.
To support your requirement, add the following parameters for userstore configuration in the `deployment.toml` file available at `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf` as given below.

```
[user_store]
username_java_script_regex = '^[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$'
username_java_regex='^[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}'
```

You can provide a suitable regular expression to match your requirement. Note that `username_java_script_regex` is used by front-end components for username validation.

Refer [here](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/using-email-address-as-the-username/) for more information.

Comment: Mam after integrating it sign up in wso2 using email with more than 30 character is possible but using the token generated in /ouath/introscpect api it is giving 401 unauthorized. How to fix this???? please help

Answer (score 1):

By default, the username in the WSO2 is not allowed as email. You need to configure the product to support username as email. You can follow this [documentation](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/using-email-address-as-the-username/) to achieve this

Comment: Sir i have already done so. This is an error regarding wrong use of format of email.Please Help