# Changing the username_java_script_regex causes a 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

This question is a follow up for the following question where I was trying to perform sign-ups in WSO2 IS 5.9.0 with emails having more than 30 characters.

[My Previous Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59487745/getting-following-error-while-creating-a-user-in-wso2-is-5-9-0-using-scim-api)

So as the solution said to apply the given regex.

```
[user_store]
username_java_script_regex = '^[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$'
username_java_regex='^[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}'
```

Then I was able to perform sign-ups with emails having more than 30 characters but ouath2 API's got compromised.

After integrating it sign up in wso2 using email with more than 30 character is possible but using the token generated in /ouath/introscpect API it is giving 401 unauthorized.

My deployment.toml file-------->

```
[server]
hostname = "localhost"
node_ip = "127.0.0.1"
base_path = "https://$ref{server.hostname}:${carbon.management.port}"

[super_admin]
username = "admin"
password = "admin"
create_admin_account = true

[http_access_log]                                                               #enabling http logs in certain pattern
pattern = "%h %l %u %t %r %s %b %{Referer}i %{User-Agent}i %T"

[tenant_mgt]
enable_email_domain= true

[user_store]
type = "database"
scim_enabled = true
user_name_attribute = "mail"
username_java_script_regex = '^[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$'
username_java_regex='^[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}'

[database.identity_db]
type = "mysql"
url= "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/regdb?useSSL=false"
username = "regadmin"
password = "regadmin"
driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

[database.shared_db]
type = "mysql"
url= "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/regdb?useSSL=false"
username = "regadmin"
password = "regadmin"
driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

[[cache.manager]]
name = "LocalClaimInvalidationCache"
timeout = "300"
capacity = "5000"

[carbon_health_check]
enable= true

[keystore.primary]
name = "wso2carbon.jks"
password = "wso2carbon"

[admin_service.wsdl]
enable = true
```

Comment: Did the /ouath/introscpect api work previously? The API is by default protected. Can you post the cURL command used to call the introspection endpoint? Also I am asuming you have enabled email as username in the server by adding the configs in this doc https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/using-email-address-as-the-username/

Comment: When you call the /ouath/introscpect endpoint, can you try appending tenant domain at the end of the email? ex: myemail@gmail.com@carbon.super or myemail@gmail.com@sometenant.com

Comment: Yes sir the ouath/introspect worked fine before.

Comment: Curl Request-
curl --location --request POST 'https://XXXXXXXXX/oauth2/introspect' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXX' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'token=eyJ4NXQiOiJOMkkyT1RneVltUTRNakF3WXpNNU1XVTNPVEF4TURGaVlUZ3hNakExTURJeFlXWXlNbVV4TnciLCJraWQiOiJOMkkyT1RneVltUTRNakF3WXpNNU1XVTNPVEF4TURGaVlUZ3hNakExTURJeFlXWXlNbVV4TndfUlMyNTYiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhbWFud3N...........ifJ3C3KvMyOAn-FX7Q' \
--data-urlencode 'token_type_hint=access_token'

Comment: Yes I am using email as username

Comment: For introspect api we only need token

Comment: 401 means you are not authorized to access the resource. Introspect API should be authorized with a token issued to a user who has at least one role assigned with the `/permission/admin/manage/identity/applicationmgt/view` permission. This is because in the `identity.xml` file we have define the permission level of each REST API. So your Authorization header token should be obtained for a user with the mentioned permission. Try again with such a token.

Comment: Sir do I change anything I change anything in deployment.toml file as I am using WSO2 IS 5.9.0

Comment: What Nipun Thathsara has mentioned above is to use a privileged user for the authorization header. Since you seem to be using basic authentication, use the credentials of a user with the admin role, and try.